# how to post a json array from angularjs controller to php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, json

I used the $http.post() method. Here is the code

```
$scope.checkout = function(){
         $http({
        url:"checkout.php",
        data : $.param($scope.orders),
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.sdata = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
});
    }
```

My json array is stored in $scope.orders and i want to  post to checkout.php which is in the same folder.

And in the php page my code is

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $postData = json_decode($data);
    foreach ($postData as $post) {
    echo $post->name;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $post->price;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $post->quantity;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

But its not working.

And please tell me how to redirect to checkout.php. Basically I am posting this data on a button click and i want to redirect to checkout.php after the data is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your php is expecting data sent as content type `application/json` which is the default for `$http`.

However you are changing the default content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

If you want the `$http` to stay the same you need to use `$_POST` not `file_get_contents()`

If you want the php to stay the same you need to remove the content type header from `$http` and not use `$.param` to serialize the data.

Also note that if you want to redirect to `checkout.php` after the ajax the redirect won't contain the post data so you would need to store that in session to make this work. Otherwise you probably don't need `$http` at all and should just use browser to submit the form and not intercept to send with `$http`

Comment: Sorry I am new to angular can you tell me how will I use a session variable in a js file.Because the controller code is in a separate js file.

Comment: session I am referring to is server session. Each time you call that `checkout.php` it is a new instance so the data won't exist if you redirect to it but it would if you submit form using default browser process

Comment: Can I use angular services to use variables across various pages

Comment: Not to load new page , javascript is not persistent.